# JQuery Waypoints - infinite scroll "shortcut" makes unnecessary and erroneous AJAX requests?

Tags: jquery-waypoints

Running into a problem while trying to implement Waypoints infinite scroll example from http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/shortcuts/infinite-scroll/.

Here is a JSFiddle to demonstrate my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/jmankin/75g6cap2/5/

HTML

```
<div class="infinite-container">
<div class="infinite-item">Not much content</div>
</div>

<a class="infinite-more-link" 
    href="/gh/get/response.html/jermifer/jsfiddle/tree/master/waypoints-infinite/"
>Loading...</a>
```

JS

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint.Infinite({
     element: $('div.infinite-container')[0]
});
```

In instances where the 1st "infinite-more-link" is "above the fold" of the viewport on page load (i.e. the "inifinite-item" content is too short to require scrolling), the script correctly makes an AJAX call to the link href and loads the requested content.

***However***, it then prematurely--and seemingly incorrectly--proceeds to make the AJAX call to the 2nd "infinite-more-link" even though that is "below the fold" when it loads.

***Secondly***, from then on, scrolling to the bottom of the page (what would technically now be the 2nd "infinite-item" content element) will cause an AJAX call to the originally requested URL (the one that the client explicitly addressed), which is completely baffling. Under normal circumstances, it does this over and over again. In jsFiddle, it just does it the once, but that still gives you an idea of what I mean.

(***Note:*** I'm not able to know ahead of time the length of the content I'd be loading, which is why I can't guarantee that the user will have to scroll down to see the 1st "infinite-more-link.")

Comment: The behavior you're describing becomes extra clear when I add `onBeforePageLoad` and `onAfterPageLoad` callback options with a debugger statement inside. If you do that you will see a before handler fire, then the new content load, then a second before fire, then both afters fire. This has all the smells of a bug in the library. Would you be willing to open an issue at https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints/issues and basically copy all of this question in there, including that JSFiddle link?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to contribute to solve this issue in the library in this link, please check that: https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints/issues/384 - Best wishes!